# How to create an index using Whoosh

Tags: python, search, indexing, unicode, whoosh

I am trying to use Whoosh for text searching for the first time. I want to search for documents  containing the word "XML". But  because  I am new to Whoosh,  I just wrote a program that search for a word from a document. Where the document is a text file (myRoko.txt)

```
import os, os.path
from whoosh import index
from whoosh.index import open_dir
from whoosh.fields import Schema, ID, TEXT
from whoosh.qparser import QueryParser
from whoosh.query import *

if not os.path.exists("indexdir3"):
   os.mkdir("indexdir3")

schema =  Schema(name=ID(stored=True), content=TEXT)
ix = index.create_in("indexdir3", schema)
writer = ix.writer()
path = "myRoko.txt"

with open(path, "r") as f:
   content = f.read()
   f.close()
   writer.add_document(name=path, content= content)

  writer.commit()

  ix = open_dir("indexdir3")
  query_b = QueryParser('content', ix.schema).parse('XML')
  with ix.searcher() as srch:
    res_b = srch.search(query_b)
    print res_b[0]
```

The above code is supposed to print the document that contain the word "XML".  However the code return the following error:

```
    raise ValueError("%r is not unicode or sequence" % value)

    ValueError: 'A large number of documents are now represented and stored      
    as XML document on the web. Thus ................
```

What could be the cause of this error?

Answer (score 2):

You have a Unicode problem. You should pass unicode strings to the indexer. For that, you need to open the text file as unicode:

```
import codecs
with codecs.open(path, "r","utf-8") as f:
   content = f.read()
```

and use unicode string for file name:

```
path = u"myRoko.txt"
```

After fixes I got this result:

```
<Hit {'name': u'myRoko.txt'}>
```

Comment: Thank you. Sorry I have on break

Comment: @user3422243 sorry I didnt get you, is this answers your question? If yes, consider to accept it and upvote

Comment: Yes it has answer my question. Thank you once again

Answer (score 0):

```
writer.add_document(name=unicode(path), content=unicode(content))
```

It has to be UNICODE